# How to bypass sites that blocks tor?

Tags: exit-relays, blocked, cloudflare

Tor has many mechanisms for obfuscating its traffic to prevent packet inspection. The "meek" pluggable transport helps to hide this deep packet inspection and hide it as https traffic. (This works fine for outbound traffic). But the problem is that all the tor exit nodes are available through the TorDNSEL. So reverse proxies like cloudflare still easily blocks tor. (Inbound traffic being blocked here). How do i REALLY bypass any server i want (even if it means chaining tor with something else like a vpn)?

Comment: I don't know your situation, but my opinion on this is that if the site cares so much about your data (as in, *aquiring it*) that it goes out of it's way to block most means of hiding it, it's not a site you want to be using. In worst case, you could spin up generic vm or docker container with VPN that the website doesn't block, coupled with a standard browser, so chrome/chromium or mozilla, then discard it altogether after use.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know this is not possible

All tor relay UP addresses are publicly available, including exit ones. Any webmasters that choose to block them can, in fact Tor Project operates a dedicated list for this purpose. Cloudflare also provides an option for sites using their services to block Tor traffic.

Webmasters sometimes block for security purposes (some people do use the Tor network illegitimately, and there is the stereotype that Tor is only for illegal purposes) or occasionally because they cannot appropriately track you for various reasons. Either way, there is zero you can do to get around this, besides maybe politely ask the website owner to unblock Tor users

And as far your suggestions of using a VPN with Tor, this is a **very** bad idea and the docs recommend against it

Comment: As for "ask the website owner to unblock Tor users", see [Stack Exchange IP Block Exemption Policy (Tor)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398349/stack-exchange-ip-block-exemption-policy-tor)

Comment: See also [Stop telling Tor users to contact support for registration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391323/stop-telling-tor-users-to-contact-support-for-registration-if-their-request-wil)

Comment: See also [How to create a StackExchange account on Tor?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/23977/how-to-create-a-stackexchange-account-on-tor)

Comment: Are you a bot @MichaelAltfield?

Comment: No. I'm a human. This human: https://michaelaltfield.net