# How to create a StackExchange account on Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, censorship

How can I create an account on stackexchange.com using Tor Browser?

I am an [at-risk user](https://community.torproject.org/user-research/personas/) who uses Tor for physical security. For the safety of my family, I only access the Internet with TAILS.

I need to ask a question on StackExchange, but when I try to create an account in TAILS on Tor Browser, I get this error:

```
You cannot register at this time. If you continue to find this error, contact us.
```

I've tried using different email providers and reset my identity to use a new exit node over-and-over. Sometimes I get this error message instead

```
Something went wrong. Please contact us at community-support@stackoverflow.email for assistance.
```

I'm also a contributor to Wikipedia, and -- because I have a risk to the life of my family -- I was able to get my account whitelisted for [IP Block Exemption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:IP_block_exemption) so that I can use Wikipedia with Tor. Is there a similar process to protect at-risk people (eg refugees fleeing gang or State violence) on Stack Exchange?

How can I signup for an account on Stack Exchange using Tor Browser?

Comment: See also [Stack Exchange IP Block Exemption Policy (Tor)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398349/stack-exchange-ip-block-exemption-policy-tor)

Comment: See also [Stop telling Tor users to contact support for registration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391323/stop-telling-tor-users-to-contact-support-for-registration-if-their-request-wil)

Answer (score 1):

It's an old problem here: even Tor community you're at is **not** available inside Tor as an onion resource :D To get rid of that a decentralized authentication must be implemented, so the risk that is mitigated by this ridiculous IP blocking - the spam and abuse - will be eliminated.

Comment: Yeah, probably a lot of useful questions and answers won't ever make it into this Tor SE site because our userbase cannot register to ask or answer questions. Is "centralized authentication" still required in SE sites that don't use a subdomain off the stackexchange.com TLD? For example, stackoverflow.com and superuser.com?

Comment: sadly, yes :( They don't let you have your authentication data